# What is the probability that all faces have appeared in some order in some six consecutive rolls?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, dice

> We roll a 6-sided die n times. What is the probability that all faces have appeared in some order in some six consecutive rolls?

Is there a way to do this without resorting to markov chains?

Comment: Given the condition that the six tosses be consecutive, I think something equivalent to markov is the way to go.  Set up a recursion.

Comment: Why does consecutive mean a markov chain to you?

Comment: It doesn't, exactly.  To me it means "states", as you are only concerned with the number of distinct tosses in your latest run.   That's why a recursion is so easy to establish.

Comment: What do you mean by 'in some order'?

Comment: @Bram28 I'd guess some permutation of $123456$.

Comment: @lulu Outside of establishing a Markov chain with $\sum\limits_{n=1}^6{6\choose n}\cdot n!$ states, I don't see how a recursion is so easy to establish

Comment: @DonThousand That would be my guess as well, but I would see that as not in any order at all ... and you could phrase the question that a little easier then as well ... so I am not sure. OP?

Comment: @DonThousand  Consider the first $6$ tosses.  Either you are done or at some point you hit a duplicate in which case you restart.  Hence the recursion.

Comment: @Bram28 I agree that OP should clarify. I interpreted it as the probability that there is some permutation of $123456$ as a contiguous subsequence of the $n$ rolls.

Comment: @Bram28 as Don Thousand says, in any permutation

Comment: @lulu No, that doesn't work... It's any permutation of $123456$, not just the standard order.

Comment: @DonThousand what makes you say that?

Comment: @lulu Let's do a quick example. Consider the following set of rolls: $12342651$. That contains a sequence of $123456$. But your algorithm would disagree.

Comment: @DonThousand  Oh, good point. My error.

Comment: @lulu “Staeting over”  implies you can’t get the six in a row starting at the second. But if you have the rolls $1,2,3,4,5,1,6$ you’ve got your six in a row. In fact, you need to “wind back” when you get a repetition.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews  Yes, you are right.  I need to know which state I jump into when I get my duplicate. One could also keep track of that, but it is not so pleasant.

Comment: So the Markov process requires seven states. A start state, and the states that the last $i$ rolls are distinct, for $i=1,\dots,6.$

Comment: @DonThousand you definitely don’t need that many states. You only need $7.$

Comment: The Markov chain solution will use https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absorbing_Markov_chain but its also not very easy to see

Comment: From a quick bit of plugging the Markov chain into Wolfram Alpha, the dominant terms gives a probability something like $$1-1.063\cdot (0.987)^n.$$ The other eigenvalues are all of absolute value $<0.26.$

Comment: If the dice is fair the anwer is easy, it is just $1/6^6$

Comment: @TomKeen reread. It definitely depends on $n.$ Not sure what problem you think you are solving.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can compute the result numerically by a recursion or (equivalently) by a Markov chain formulation. The advantage of the former is that you can do some asympotics (as Thomas Andrews showed in the comments).

For completeness, here's the recursion.

Let define the state, $X_t$ as the length of the longest trailing subsequence with different values, after $t=1,2 \cdots$ tries, if the target subsequence (six different values) has not yeat appear, $X_t=6$ otherwise. Let $p(x,t)=P(X_t =x)$.

Hence $X_1=1$ , and we want $p(6,t)$

The recursion is

$$ p(x,t+1)=\begin{cases}
\displaystyle{
\frac{6-(x-1)}{6} p(x-1,t) + \frac16 \sum_{k=x}^5  p(k,t)} & {\rm if } \;  x=1,2\cdots 5 \\
\displaystyle{
 p(6,t) + \frac{1}{6} p(5,t)} & {\rm if }\;  x=6
\end{cases}
$$

This can be computed numerically, for example with a spreadsheet:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1SJRlXaaS2K1YYNfa7QFcJ29Ks6M2nVf9mlbIteNWwrY

The last column shows the approximation from Thomas Andrews.